# Bootstrapping Standard Error vs Standard deviation

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, bootstrap, standard-error

I am studying for an exam and would really appreciate some guidance as I am new to stats.

I am and having difficulty understanding the difference between the:

1. standard error of a bootstrap distribution
2. standard error of a bootstrap statistic
3. standard deviation of a bootstrap statistic.

From my understanding, 1 and 3 are the same thing but I am not sure about 2?
Is there are difference between the SE of a bootstrap distribution and the SE of a bootstrap statistic? If so, any explanation on what it is and/or how to calculate it?

All advise will be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the difference between standard deviation and standard error? For instance, if I take nine observations that are distributed as $N(0, 1)$, what is the standard deviation, and what is the standard error? (This is a trick question. Do you see why?)

Comment: Thank you heaps for your comment! Yes, I do mean what is the difference between the standard deviation and standard error for the bootstrap. So a mean in the case of N(0,1) the sd =  square root(1/9)  = 0.333 and the SE = 0.33/square root 9 = 0.111? I am sorry I am still confused! any further advise? Thank you!

Comment: The standard deviation is $1$. The trick question was that standard error refers to a particular parameter estimate. Yes, the standard error of the mean is $\sigma/\sqrt{9}$, but there’s a standard error of the variance and a standard error of the standard deviation! My suggestion is to review these fundamentals before you tackle bootstrap standard errors.

Comment: Thank you! 
Ok I did some background reading.. here is my final attempt. 

1) The SE of a statistic is the approximate standard deviation (sd) of a statistical sample population. 

Because the bootstrap distribution is our ‘best guess’ at the population distribution, the SE for the test statistic from the bootstrap) will be the standard deviation of the bootstrap. 

2) The bootstrap distribution will also have an SE because the re-samples are estimates of a population. Therefore, the SE of the bootstrap will be the bootstraps SD divided by the number of resamples??
Thank you